# How to force Ruby to store a small number as 32 bit integer

Tags: .net, ruby, memcached, membase, couchbase

I have a .NET client which store some numbers as 32 bit integer in memcached.

I can not use that numbers in Ruby client nor I can't store number which could be consumed in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`Array#pack`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Array%3apack) and `String#unpack` methods:

```
> [42].pack('l')
# => "*\x00\x00\x00"
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help you

http://bindata.rubyforge.org/

You can store the required data in the way you want.